# How to insert figure into a footnote in LaTeX?

Tags: floats, errors, pdftex, footnotes, includegraphics

I want to insert a small figure into a footnote. However, LaTeX gives an error.

My code is:

```
\footnote{Bla-bla-bla

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{Figures/myFigure}
\label{fig:myFig}
\end{figure}

bla-bla-bla.}
```

The message is:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file ./Figures/myFigure.pdf): PDF inclusi
on: found PDF version <1.6>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
[20]) [21]

! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

Thanks!

Comment: just use `\includegraphics` you do not want a `figure` environment, thats only purpose is to allow a figure to float to another page to help with page breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\includegraphics` you do not want a `figure` environment, thats only purpose is to allow a figure to float to another page to help with page breaking.